# Unity netcode is there a way to create a network variable that is list or a array (Unity, Netcode)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

With unity netcode is there a way to create a network variable that is list or array

Comment: in low-end networking, it's basically syncing data via byte[]. You can convert any type of data into byte[] for streaming. There is some basic tutorial like syncing tutorial: https://youtu.be/K6kWLszpykM

Answer (score 2):

Netcode for Gameobjects has `NetworkList<T>`.

[Documentation for NetworkList](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkList-1.html)

Comment: updated link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkList-1.html